# Replacing a value with a new value

Tags: java

If i have :

```
    if(ipp instanceof TCPPacket){
        TCPPacket tcp = (TCPPacket)ipp;
        int destPort = tcp.dst_port;
        int srcPort = tcp.src_port;
    }
```

How to replace destPort and srcPort with a defined number like 10 ?

Comment: hey answerers! by replacing OP means "setting". =)

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you want to achieve?

Comment: `tcp.dst_port = 10`? Are you trying to implement a firewall of some kind? If so, check out **iptables**.

Comment: in the TCPPacket class or just the local vars (destPort, srcPort)?

Comment: Can you link to the TCPPacket class that you are using?  It doesn't appear to be part of standard Java class library...

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
if(ipp instanceof TCPPacket){
    TCPPacket tcp = (TCPPacket)ipp;
    int destPort = 10;
    int srcPort = 10;
}
```

Edit on second thought-

If you're actually trying to set the values of the `TCPPacket`, and [this](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/javadoc/jpcap/packet/TCPPacket.html) is the `TCPPacket` class you are using, you can just do this:

```
if(ipp instanceof TCPPacket){
    TCPPacket tcp = (TCPPacket)ipp;
    tcp.dst_port = 10;
    tcp.src_port = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like...?

```
if(ipp instanceof TCPPacket){
    TCPPacket tcp = (TCPPacket)ipp;
    int destPort = 10;
    int srcPort = 10;
}
```

But I may have misinterpreted your question, did you mean how to set `tcp.dst_port` and `tcp.src_port`?